# How to construct the WADL file to get following Java interface

Tags: java, rest, interface, wadl

I am very new to REST services .. I want to create a WADL which I will be converting to Java interface to create and expose a Rest web service .. So .. I need to create a WADL to get the following java interface :-

```
@Path("/getData")
public interface MainData {


    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/retrieve/")
    public DataResponse retrieveDataOperation(@QueryParam("id") int id);

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/insert/")
    public DataResponse insertDataOperation(String message);

    @PUT
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/update/")
    public DataResponse updateDataOperation(String message);

    @DELETE
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/delete/")
    public DataResponse deleteDataOperation(@QueryParam("id") int id);

}
```

So far I tried to create the following WADL to get the above interface :-

```
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02 wadl.xsd"
    xmlns:ns1="http://services.test.com/schema/bs/bom/v01/GetAllTypeDesignators"

    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
<grammars>
  <include href="MainData.xsd" />
</grammars>

<resources base="http://localhost:8082">

<resource path="getData" id="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData">

        <resource path="/retrieve/" >
             <method name="GET" id="retrieveDataOperation">
                <request>
                    <param  type="xs:int" style="query" name="id"/>
                </request>
                <response>
                     <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:DataResponse"/>
                 </response>
               </method>
        </resource>

   <resource path="/delete/" >
     <method name="DELETE" id="deleteDataOperation">
        <request>
          <param  type="xs:int" style="query" name="id"/>
         </request>
       <response>
         <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:DataResponse"/>
       </response>
      </method>
    </resource>

   <resource path="/insert/" >
       <method name="POST" id="insertDataOperation">
          <request>
             <param name="message" type="xs:string" />
           </request>
               <response>
                   <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:DataResponse"/>
                </response>
            </method>
          </resource>

    <resource path="/update/" >
  <method name="PUT" id="updateDataOperation">
     <request>
        <param name="message" type="xs:string" />
     </request>
    <response>
      <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:DataResponse"/>
    </response>
   </method>
</resource>

</resource>
</resources>
</application>
```

But I am not able to get the Java interface above after converting this WADL to Java .. While converting in Apache CXF it also shows following exception :- `WADLToJava Error: java.lang.NullPointerException`
Please help me to to modify the WADL to get the exact java interface above .. Am I doing in right way .. Please help ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just check your WADL and it looks ok, few minor mistakes but nothing which point to your error. Also, I have used command line tool wadl2java;

```
wadl2java -d /output/dir -interface /input/wadl/application.wadl
```

Here is corrected WADL;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:ns1="http://services.test.com/schema/bs/bom/v01/GetAllTypeDesignators">
    <grammars>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://services.test.com/schema/bs/bom/v01/GetAllTypeDesignators">
            <xs:element name="dataResponse" type="ns1:dataResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="dataResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="param1" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="param2" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8082">
        <resource path="getData" id="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData">
            <resource path="/retrieve/" >
                <method name="GET" id="retrieveDataOperation">
                    <request>
                        <param  type="xs:int" style="query" name="id"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:dataResponse"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="/delete/" >
                <method name="DELETE" id="deleteDataOperation">
                    <request>
                        <param  type="xs:int" style="query" name="id"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:dataResponse"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="/insert/" >
                <method name="POST" id="insertDataOperation">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*">
                            <param name="message" style="plain" type="xs:string" />
                        </representation>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:dataResponse"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="/update/" >
                <method name="PUT" id="updateDataOperation">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="*/*">
                            <param name="message" style="plain" type="xs:string" />
                        </representation>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json" element="ns1:dataResponse"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

You should post your `MainData.xsd`, I'll bet that inside your XSD relies your error.

**UPDATE:**

It appears that param name must be lowerCase of the param type if it used in "representation". I have just check the source code of the wadl2java (cxf-tools-wadlto-jaxrs-3.0.1-sources.jar) and concluded that modification of generator is required. Problematic line is in class `org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.jaxrs.SourceGenerator:1044` which looks like `elementParamName = elementParamType.toLowerCase();` You should report that on [Apache CXF jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF) or modify code by yourself.

Alternative is to set your `message` param as `@QueryParam`, you can do that by replacing;

```
    <representation mediaType="*/*">
        <param name="message" style="plain" type="xs:string" />
    </representation>
```

with this;

```
    <param name="message" style="query" type="xs:string" />
```

but in that case your interface method will look like;

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/insert/")
DataResponse insertDataOperation(@QueryParam("message") String message);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect .. but one major issue is there .. After converting to java file from WADL ... I am getting the following :- `DataResponse insertDataOperation(String string);` .. where as it should be actually `DataResponse insertDataOperation(String message);` ... I am getting for both **insert** and **update**

Comment: I tried with `<param name="message" style="query" type="xs:string" />` and I am getting `DataResponse insertDataOperation(@QueryParam("message") String message);` .. but I want simple `(String message)` and not **@QueryParam("message")** in it .. is there no way to avoid it ?

Comment: As I said, you can update org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.jaxrs.SourceGenerator, to return "name" param instead lower case of the param type. It is way how it is implemented, report it on cxf jira.

Comment: Everything is fine ..just one last question then ..See I don't know much about WADL .. so may be something silly it sounds .. but anyway the question is :- I am getting `DataResponse insertDataOperation(@QueryParam("message") String message);` .. but  what I want is it should be like `public DataResponse insertDataOperation(@QueryParam("message") String message);` .. so anyway to add **public** before all those methods .. pls check my question ..the expected output contains **public** before all the methods ..is there anyways that I can modify the WADL to get it?? that's the last thing I want

Comment: I'm not sure, because public modifier is redundant in java interface. So your both cases are actually the same. If you really need that, I'll investigate it.

Comment: Yes  pls .. I really need it .. I also updated `org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.jaxrs.SourceGenerator` as you suggested and used the latest `cxf-tools-wadlto-jaxrs.jar` .. but it results the same ...no Idea what to do to get the expected java interface .....     Thanks for your support

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary, could you shed some light what for do you need the public modifier for the interface methods?

Comment: @mijer I want to make all my methods as public so that it can be used in the other classes in different packages .. It's actually the standered followed here and I am just following what the requirement and the standered defined and I have been told .. :)

Comment: All the methods in the interfaces are implicitely public, so it is not necessary to specify the modifier explicitely.

Comment: @mijer .. yes .. you are right .. I asked this question because I found that when I use **WSDL2Java** to convert a WSDL file into a java interface, the converted Java interface have public defined explicitly before the methods .. so I was wondering why **WADL2Java** is unable to produce **public** before the method name (Though I know it is public by default)

Comment: Didn't have time over weekend. If it isn't too late, I'll modify that parser for you, if you really need it.